# Simple histogram for numeric data on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, histogram

Other databases have good functions for histogram... For example Hive offers [`histogram_numeric(numeric_column,b)`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)), where `b` is the "number non-uniformly spaced bins".

Is there a library for PostgreSQL that offers a similar function for numeric columns?

Important: [this Wiki function](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Histogram) is ugly, is not simple.

Comment: Are you looking for [width_bucket](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#id-1.5.8.9.6.2.2.29.1.1.1)?

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL is better! It has the `ntile` window function:

```
SELECT n, ntile(3) OVER (ORDER BY n)
FROM generate_series(1, 20) AS n;

 n  | ntile 
----+-------
  1 |     1
  2 |     1
  3 |     1
  4 |     1
  5 |     1
  6 |     1
  7 |     1
  8 |     2
  9 |     2
 10 |     2
 11 |     2
 12 |     2
 13 |     2
 14 |     2
 15 |     3
 16 |     3
 17 |     3
 18 |     3
 19 |     3
 20 |     3
(20 rows)
```